# Wordpress 3.3.1 url parameters not working

Tags: wordpress, url-parameters

This was working in `wordpress 3.3` but when i upgraded didn't work.
Whenever I type url http://www.sitename.org/?email=John , wordpress automatically removes paramter and makes it http://www.sitename.org/
Due to this some of the plugins are also not working.

Does anyone know if this is `wordpress 3.3.1` fix or I have to do something in settings sections? or write in .htaccess file. I read about  %{QUERY_STRING} as GET parameters but could not understand, sorry I am just trying to figure out.
My .htaccess file contents

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You may have more luck on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
Solved. I don't know but when my friend disabled SEO plugin things started working.
Still I have not clue of what happened.
Anyways working for now.

Thank you.